# PolygonCollider2d no longer collides with CircleCollider2d after activating isTrigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I want my ball (CirleCollider2D (also with a Rigidbody2D with a physicsmaterial2D)) to bounce off a semicircle (PolygonCollider2D) and fly back.
When the ball touches the semicircle, the ball should change color.

My problem, is that if isTrigger is not activated, the ball does not perceive the collision and do not change the color, but if I activate isTrigger, the ball no longer collides but flies through the object.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if(col.tag == "color1" || col.tag == "color2")
    {
        SetRandomColor();
        return;
    }}
```

Comment: That’s what triggers do. They announce context but don’t make any difference. It has to be not a trigger just a collider to bounce off it

Answer (score 0):

Use [OnCollisionEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html). With that you dont need to care if its trigger or not.

Comment: hey, when i use OnCollisionEnter it gets kind of laggy for some reason and the color of the ball doesn't change also if there is a collision.

Comment: the link is to OnCollisionEnter2D. Are you using the 2D option?

Comment: also I think you need to add the [rigidbody2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.html) component to the elemnt you want physics the physic behaviour